# How to Add user for form authentication in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, forms-authentication, claims-based-auth

I confirgured the form authentication. but i am not able to create the users for login using form authentication .

When i want add user in the Policy for Web Application, I search User , Noticeable difference is that there are sections like Active Directory, All Users, Forms Auth & Organizations.

but i find one user in Active Directory, and don't find this user in Forms Auth.

How to Add user for form authentication in sharepoint 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your chosen user store, prior to attempt searching for the user in the store via People Picker on SP-CA you need to ensure the settings made in the web.config related to connections to the user store (membership and role providers) are replicated exactly the same on web applications for target web application, sharepoint web services and Central administration web application (last one most important in order to be able search future admin account).

The process is more complicated than this due to its many steps, but i've added some links here below to guide you through 2 of the most commo FBA Claims in SP2010.

1. http://salaudeen.blogspot.com/2011/12/configuring-ad-lds-with-sharepoint-2010.html
2. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2010/07/09/sql-server-provider-for-claims-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius